# Apache Camel: File Component IO exceptions

Tags: apache, apache-camel

While using the file component to process a large queue of messages I am getting many errors like "Too many open files" and

```
org.apache.http.nio.reactor.IOReactorException: Failure opening selector
```

What is a good approach to limit the amount of messages that is being processed to prevent any IO exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [seda queue](http://camel.apache.org/seda.html) to limit the total number of exchanges in a route that are concurrently processed.

```
from("direct:input")
    .to("seda:fileProcessor")
    .to("direct:furtherProcessing);

from("seda:fileProcessor?concurrentConsumers=100")
    .process(fileProcessor);
```

You could also look at the [throttle component](http://camel.apache.org/throttler.html), however this just limits the number of exchanges passing through the throttle for a given amount of time, rather than limiting the total number of exchanges being processed concurrently.

Note that it is also possible to increase the number of file descriptors open at any one time.  To do that on a linux system, check out [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36841/why-is-number-of-open-files-limited-in-linux)

Comment: Mmm, and what if I set up a custom thread pool with just one thread?

Comment: Yes, you can also setup a custom thread pool, though I'm not sure I'd give camel only a single thread to work with.
You can also setup a thread pool for a specific route (http://camel.apache.org/threading-model.html)
If you're seeing your file descriptors run out with a small number of threads, make sure your file objects/references are getting cleaned up / garbage collected.

Comment: Thanks @AndyN,  I have created for now a custom thread pool profile on my <throttler  executorServiceRef="oneThreadOnly"> ... so the queue will take a bit longer now... but at least no more "too many file errors"

Comment: How to close the files with camel? Still receiving too many open files even with just one thread @AndyN

Comment: If you're opening the file yourself, then you'll need to close it.  Sounds like that's what's happening.